# Vuetify bottom navigation not removing active state on route change after hard refresh

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

In my app I have a bottom navigation component set up as such:

```
<v-bottom-navigation
  v-else
  background-color="overlay"
  grow
  app
  color="primary"
>
  <v-btn
    v-for="(route, key) in routes"
    ref="link"
    :key="'route' + key"
    :to="route.to"
    min-width="48"
    class="px-0"
  >
    <span v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp">{{ route.name }}</span>
    <v-icon>{{ route.icon }}</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</v-bottom-navigation>
```

This works well, I can use it to navigate around my app as intended. When clicking one of the buttons on the bottom navigation, the button state updates as it should to show that it is active (primary color).

My routes are defined as follows:

```
routes: [
  { icon: mdiViewDashboard, name: 'Dashboard', to: '/dashboard' },
  { icon: mdiCart, name: 'Orders', to: '/orders' },
  { icon: mdiDolly, name: 'Receiving', to: '/receiving' },
  { icon: mdiClipboardText, name: 'Tasks', to: '/tasks' },
  { icon: mdiTruck, name: 'Deliveries', to: '/deliveries' },
],
```

I have an additional route `/settings` which is not part of this main navigation, but defined on the header bar of my application as such:

```
<v-btn
  aria-label="Settings"
  icon
  to="/settings"
>
  <v-icon>{{ mdiCog }}</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Since the settings button/router link is not part of the bottom navigation, when I click on the settings button, it disables the active state on the buttons in the bottom navigation, as it should since it is not part of the bottom navigation.

Here is where the odd behavior occurs:

If I am in one of the routes defined on the bottom navigation, and hard refresh the page I refresh to the proper location. From here, if I click the settings button, the router displays the settings as it should, but the active state on the bottom navigation of the stale state still shows. This only occurs on a hard refresh, if I select a bottom navigation route, and then go to settings, it removes the active state from the bottom navigation button.

In my research I thought it may be an issue with the `exact` property for the router links, but it seems to make no different.

Additionally, I set a breakpoint to display the bottom navigation on small and below, if I stretch the window to hide the bottom navigation, then shrink it to re-show, when the component is shown again, it has the proper state.

Comment: Can you share a screen recording for this problem?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/p51GJj8.gif here is a GIF of the behavior

Comment: Not able to reproduce this problem. Check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-bartik-7rffz?file=/index.html), seems to be working fine. Could you fork my sandbox, make necessary changes to reproduce this problem, and share the link here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reloading the page isn't the only way to reproduce the bug. The buttons in the navigation group appear to be toggleable both by `VItemGroup` logic and VBtn's `routable` mixin. You can replicate the problem by clicking any nav button two times and routing to `/settings` after that. If you inspect the element in that state, the active class `v-btn--active` is duplicated 3 times. Routing to another page removes only the exact matches of `v-btn--active v-btn--active`, leaving the third one on the element.

Clearly, this is not an intended behavior.

But the workaround is quite simple. Setting every button's `active-class` prop to anything but `'v-btn--active'` will do the trick.

So, for example:

```html
<v-btn
    v-for="(route, key) in routes"
    ref="link"
    :key="'route' + key"
    :to="route.to"
    min-width="48"
    class="px-0"
    active-class=""
>
    <span v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp">{{ route.name }} </span>
    <v-icon>{{ route.icon }}</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and has solved the issue for me. Thank you for your insight on this issue!